# sqlException when use ActiveJDBC

Tags: activejdbc

I use ActiveJDBC and Oracle 11g DB. When I use saveIt, i get java.sql.Exception. When I get instance or list of it, everything ok.
What I do wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument
зове, query: INSERT INTO dept (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC) VALUES (?, ?, ?), params: 45, sdfa, fdg
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.getNewSql(AutoKeyInfo.java:187)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:5704)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.execInsert(DB.java:598)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.insert(Model.java:2698)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.save(Model.java:2597)
        at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.saveIt(Model.java:2524)
        at JavaHomeTask.Dept.addPersistence(Dept.java:72)
        at JavaHomeTask.App.addRow(App.java:103)
        at JavaHomeTask.App.main(App.java:50)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument
        ... 9 more
```

And here is my code:

```
public void addPersistence() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Dept d = new Dept();
        String value;
        for (String s : getAttributesNames()) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + s + " and press Enter button:");
            value = reader.readLine();
            d.set(s, value);
        }
        d.saveIt();

    }

public List<String> getAttributesNames() {
        return Arrays.asList("DEPTNO", "DNAME", "LOC");
    }
```

Comment: can you publish entire stack trace? Also, I think one of your parameters has something wrong with it, so Oracle complains.

Comment: @ipolevoy It seems like it's entire stack trace. Schema of table dept, in which i try to insert row is
deptno Number(3)
dname varchar2(14)
loc varchar2(13)
I've also tried such way:
Dept d = new Dept();
d.set("deptno", Integer.valueOf(11));
d.set("dname", "name");
d.set("loc", "location");
d.saveIt();
But the result is the same.
PS Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I found these topic
https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/385
Seems like I have the same problem, there is no id column in my table. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the probleb is that ActiveJDBC uses id column as a Primari Key in table for recognizing which operation - INSERT or UPDATE should be used. And if table doesn't has such column, programmer should specify PK manually using @IdName("nameOfColumn") annotation. More information you can find [here](http://javalite.io/surrogate_primary_keys)